# How do I dynamically create a named function disregarding the scope?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
var i = 'foo';
eval('function '+i+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
console.log(foo); // [Function: foo]
```

This does not:

```
['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    eval('function '+i+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

Apparently, the `forEach` function or its subordinate scope confuses things. I checked that the `bar` function is available during, but it does not survive outside.

Comment: I guess I'd wonder why you feel the need to create functions from strings in the first place. You're most certainly losing some optimizations, and the presence of `eval()` is even going to wipe out some optimizations in the enclosing code.

Comment: Metaprogramming. This is three layers deep into a [yak](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving), and if JS had any semblance of a native [MOP](http://enwp.org/Metaobject#Metaobject_protocol), I would not need to resort to string eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    this.eval('function '+i+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});

['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    window.eval('function '+i+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});

['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
  eval.call(null, 'function ' + i + '(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
  // same
  // eval.call(window, 'function ' + i + '(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `forEach` callback creates a closure.  Anything defined in that closure is close off to the world.  You can imaging the final result of your code being equivalent to this:

```
function() {
    function bar() { ... }
    function quux() { ... }
}
// bar and quux are out of scope here :(
```

You will need some object to append those functions to if you want them available to the world.  `window` is the cheapest, or something like this is a little better:

```
var myScope = {};
['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    eval('myScope["'+i+'"] = function(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});
myScope.bar();  // woo hoo!
```

Comment: If you're going to 'export' the function by attaching it to an outer object (`myScope`), is there any reason to use `eval` any longer?

Comment: Not really, but that's not what the question is about.  IMO, there is rarely a use for eval ever... ever.

Comment: Thanks for the praise - not sure why people post solutions without the explanation (re: accepted answer).  If the user gets the explanation, hopefully it prevents him from asking more questions...

Answer (score 1):

The problem of `forEach` is that `eval` runs inside an anonymous function, so the created variables will be confined inside that scope, not accessible from the outside.

To fix it, just iterate your array in other ways that don't require a wrapping function. For example:

- `for` loop:

  ```
  var names = ['bar', 'quux'];
  for(var i=0; i<names.length; ++i)
      eval('function '+names[i]+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
  ```
- `for...of` (ECMAScript 6)

  ```
  for(var i of ['bar', 'quux'])
      eval('function '+i+'(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
  ```

Note this won't work in strict mode:

> **[10.4.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2.1) Strict Mode Restrictions**
>
> The eval code cannot instantiate variable or function bindings in the
>   variable environment of the calling context that invoked the eval if
>   either the code of the calling context or the eval code is [strict
>   code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1). Instead such bindings are instantiated in a new
>   [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) that is only accessible to the eval code.

Comment: Disclaimer: I strongly discourage using evil `eval`.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer since it satisfies OP's requirement of named functions. Why that's a requirement is not clear, but if you eliminate it then there's no reason I can see to use eval().

Comment: I was thinking of `for` loops too, but then you're basically putting a function declaration where a statement should go. Browsers accept it (though with some inconsistencies), but strict mode doesn't

Comment: @Oriol I think most people will agree with you that eval() is problematic for a variety of reasons. Do you know another way to satisfy the named function requirement without using it? I do not.

Comment: @Oriol and now I notice that it's your answer I'm commenting on, so I'm guessing not. Anyway, good answer!

Comment: Yeah, seems to fail in Chrome anyway (in strict mode): http://jsfiddle.net/2v8fp307/

Comment: @sixfingeredman It doesn't work in strict mode because then `eval` has restrictions, which also affect all other answers and OP's code. But I think in non strict code it should work, even if it's a function declaration inside a `for` (which expects statements). `eval(x)` parses `x` as a `Program` ([15.1.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1)). And a `FunctionDeclaration` is a `Program` ([A.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5)).

Comment: Yeah, I'm 99% sure this whole thing is an XY Problem anyway. But you're right. The `eval()` is actually the statement for the `for`, so that wouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple assign function to a global object:

```
['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    eval('window.' + i + ' = function(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One more answer! Use the `window` object:

```
['bar', 'quux'].forEach(function(i) {
    eval('window.'+i+' = function(param) { this.param = param; return this; }');
});
```